# Email delivery status in amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I am doing some testing on sanbox account for Amazon Web Services (SES) .
I have to maintain the delivery report of each email (Deliver, Complaints,Bounce, Rejected).
I have the message id.
Can you please tell me how to find out the email delivery status using message id.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can be notified either via email or SNS about bounces/complaints etc.

To get SNS notifications, read this:
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html

to get email notifications read this:
  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications-via-email.html

Comment: I am doing testing on sandbox account till now I don't have production access. I want to maintain the status of each email in automated way not by email notification. Which api request or service is available for this information please guide me on that.

Comment: delivery (success) notifications are now supported as well

Comment: how long does it take to get reliably notified of bounce or delivery from the point of sending the email?

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to this page.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/monitor-sending-activity-api.html

In summary, you can use GetSendStatistics API to tackle your concern.
Hope it will be helpful for u.

Thanks.

Comment: Pls refer this link too: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_GetSendStatistics.html