# Track email delivery status in AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses

I'm using AWS SES for sending emails and I want to track if a mail has been delivered to the given address. From [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/monitor-using-event-publishing.html) I can see that SES supports publishing events to kinesis/SNS/Cloudwatch.

I tried using Cloudwatch and it is only [saving metric info](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch/client/get_metric_data.html) or [overall statistics](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses/client/get_send_statistics.html) rather than the info per email id, ie, if I send an email to a non-existing id (account is out of sandbox), then SES will return me a messageId saying that the email has been delivered.

Though there is a metric in Cloudwatch log for Bounce event, I am unable to get the info confirming if the email is delivered or not from this.

Is there a way to confirm if an email has been delivered successfully in SES ?
SNS has the capability for sending notifications to the subscribers, but what I'm expecting or want to confirm is, can I accomplish the same using CloudWatch ?

None of below helped me answer my issue,

1. [Email delivery status in amazon SES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379979/email-delivery-status-in-amazon-ses)
2. [Email status in AWS SES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67945478/email-status-in-aws-ses)
3. [Get email status per destination separately, when sending an email group of destinations in AWS SES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74635822/get-email-status-per-destination-separately-when-sending-an-email-group-of-dest)
4. [Get success status AWS SES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70754734/get-success-status-aws-ses)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "delivered successfully"?  A receiving email system may tell SES that the message has been accepted but then drop it.  SES has no way of knowing that.  SES does have the ability to set up [notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/monitor-using-event-publishing.html) and I've used these for "hard" bounces.  The open and click events are dependent on the receiving mail client and are difficult to get reliably.